SDK problem - Your Android SDK is missing
I clicked new project on a software called Android Studio after the installation was completed. So I'm getting this error . Your Android SDK is missin, out of date or corrupted
Once you have Android Studio on your machine, the next step is to start a new project. This is a straightforward process, but you’ll need to make a few decisions that will impact on your Android app development going forward.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
